# How to modify the slam_gmapping node on a turtlebot?

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, catkin, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to modify the slam_gmapping node on my Turtlebot (Kobuki) (Ubuntu 12.04).

I have a working catkin workspace and have built my own nodes that work with slam_gmapping, but now I want to modify it.

I downloaded the slam_gmapping source to my workspace and tried to build it, but get this error...

> -- ==> add_subdirectory(slam_gmapping/gmapping)
> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72
> (find_package):   Could not find a
> configuration file for package
> openslam_gmapping.
>
> Set openslam_gmapping_DIR to the
> directory containing a CMake
> configuration   file for
> openslam_gmapping.  The file will have
> one of the following names:
>
> ```
> openslam_gmappingConfig.cmake
> openslam_gmapping-config.cmake
> ```

How does one "set openslam_gmapping_DIR"?  is that a line in some file?  But even if it were, neither of those suggested files exist on this system.

this is the failing line:

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED nav_msgs
> openslam_gmapping roscpp rostest tf)

It seems openslam_gmapping package does not exist on this machine (at least not with that name) in any workspace.  Maybe it was built special for the Turtlebot under a different name?
I don't have any need to build the openslam_gmapping package, just to reference the built one.  I know it exists somewhere because I can successfully build maps and "rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping".

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123756/how-to-modify-the-slam_gmapping-node-on-a-turtlebot?/) by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on 2014-01-28**:
I thought this might be an issue of needing a proper "overlay".  I followed the instructions on http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying (substituting slam_gmapping for the tutorials) but got the same error.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-29**:
@gershon hi, gmapping pacakge uses libraries built from openslam_gmapping. clone openslam_gmapping and overlay if you want to edit files of openslam_gmapping.

**Comment by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on 2014-01-29**:
Hi bvb.  I'm quite new at this.  By "clone openslam_gmappnig" I think I need to use subversion (svn) to get it on my machine, right?  Or is there another location?
Also I thought "overlay" was a ROS/Catkin concept...  how does it work with other projects?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-30**:
i mean "git clone [https://github.com/ros-perception/openslam_gmapping.git"](https://github.com/ros-perception/openslam_gmapping.git%22) or if you are not using git, just download source as zip , extract and use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally figured this out.  The problem was that if you follow the links to the openslam_gmapping dependency from the slam_gmapping page it takes to a site that provides a svn (subversion) repository that has nothing to do with ROS or Catkin.  I had no idea how to integrate that and get it building with Catkin.
Good news is, that there is a ROS/GIT repository for openslam_gmapping and it is Catkin, so when I finally got that everything builds fine and the instructions for Overlaying make it so I can build and run my versions.  Yay.

---

Originally posted by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) with karma: 73 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0